# Mongoose/MongoDB: How to push existing document into an array of another document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to append an array of hosts of one document into the hosts attribute of another document and I can't figure it out.

**Schema**

```
const ScanSchema = new Schema({
    date: { type: Date },
    hosts: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Host" }], 
});
```

I tried to add the hosts with Model.findOneAndUpdate and the $push operator. It doesn't throw any errors, but the scan document does not update.

**Contents of hostsToAdd:**

```
[{
   status: {
          state: 'up',
          reason: 'user-set',
          reason_ttl: '0',
          change_detection_color: 'red'
        },
        address: { addr: '', addrtype: 'ipv4' },
        times: {
          starttime: '',
          endtime: '',
          smoothed_rtt: '',
          rtt_variance: '',
          timeout: ''
        },
        _id: new ObjectId("63ea1cf7a7efd5be803e5ea4"),
        hostnames: [ '\n' ],
        ports: [ [Object], [Object] ],
        __v: 0
}]
```

**My Attempt**

```
    let update = 
      { "$push": 
        {
          "hosts": hostsToAdd, 
        } 
      }

    Scan.findOneAndUpdate(update, {returnNewDocument: true})
      .sort('-date')
      .populate('hosts')
      .exec()
```

Comment: according to: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html the `filter` parameter is missing in your method call

Comment: Thanks.  I figured using .sort('-date) would suffice, but filtering for and empty object did the trick.